# Identity of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ be a Fibonacci sequence with initial terms $F_0=0, F_1=1$ and $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ for $n\geqslant 1$.

Prove that $F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2=F_{2n+1}$ for $n\geqslant 0$ (with mathematical induction).

**My efforts:** For $n=0$ it is true.

Suppose that our statement holds for $0\leqslant k \leqslant n$ i.e. $F_k^2+F_{k+1}^2=F_{2k+1}$

Let's try to prove it for $k=n+1$. $$F_{2n+3}=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n+2}=F_{n+1}^2+(F_{n}^2+F_{2n+2})= ?$$

Here I'm stuck and I have applied different methods but none of them brings a positive result.

Can anyone help to complete this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295173/another-fibonacci-identity-f-2n-1-f-n2-f-n-12?rq=1

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, thanks but your link has matrix proof which is given below and proof suing binet's formula. As I said above i am interested in induction proof

Answer (score 3):

We can prove more general identity, i.e. $F_{n+m+1}=F_{m+1}F_{n+1}+F_{m}F_{n}$.

Let's prove above by mathematical induction on $n$.

For $n=0$ we have $F_{m+1}=F_{m+1}$

Suppose it is true for all $0\leqslant n \leqslant  k$.

Let's prove it for $n=k+1$ then $$F_{k+m+2}=F_{k+m}+F_{k+m+1}=(F_{m+1}F_{k}+F_{m}F_{k-1})+(F_{m+1}F_{k+1}+F_{m}F_{k})=F_{m+1}(F_k+F_{k+1})+F_m(F_{k-1}+F_k)=F_{m+1}F_{k+2}+F_mF_{k+1}$$

The first two parentheses were derived from induction assumption for $n=k-1$ or $n=k$.

Thus, we have proved our initial statement. If we put $n=m$ we get $$F_{2n+1}=F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2$$

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the matrix formulation, which is well worth knowing and [easily proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/proof-of-this-result-related-to-fibonacci-numbers):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Just compare
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{2n}=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{2n+1}&*\\*&*\end{pmatrix}
$$
with
$$
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}^2=
\begin{pmatrix}\cdots&*\\*&*\end{pmatrix}
$$
Alternatively (and equivalently), you can use induction to prove *simultaneously* that
$$
F_{2n} = F_n (F_{n+1} + F_{n-1}),
\quad
F_{2n+1}=F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2
$$

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1505284/589

Comment: Nice proof but I would like to see the induction proof

Comment: How to use induction in order to prove the second identity? Could you write the induction proof?

Comment: @RFZ, proceed as in lab bhattacharjee's answer.

Comment: I have added an answer. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

$$F_{2(n+1)+1}=F_{2n+1}+F_{2n+2}$$

$$=F_{n+1}^2+(F_{n}^2+F_{2n+2})$$

$=F_{n+1}^2+F_{n}^2+F_{n+1}(F_{n+2}+F_n)$  (Using  [Proving a Fibonacci identity: $F_{2n} = F_n (F_{n+1} + F_{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505233/proving-a-fibonacci-identity-f-2n-f-n-f-n1-f-n-1),)

$$=F_{n+1}^2+F_{n+1}F_{n+2}+F_n(\underbrace{F_n+F_{n+1}})$$

$$=F_{n+1}^2+F_{n+1}F_{n+2}+F_nF_{n+2}$$

$$=F_{n+1}^2+F_{n+2}(\underbrace{F_{n+1}+F_n})$$

$$=?$$

Answer (score 0):

We can actually prove two different identities (1) and (2), of which you were asked to prove (1):
$$F_{n+1}^2+F_{n+2}^2=F_{2n+3} \quad \text{(1)}$$
$$F_{n+2}^2-F_{n}^2=F_{2n+2} \quad \text{(2)}$$
Note that the Fibonacci numbers are numbered starting from $F_1$.

We can proceed by induction. Suppose that we have the two equations
$$F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2=F_{2n+1} \quad \text{(3)}$$
$$F_{n+1}^2-F_{n-1}^2=F_{2n} \quad \text{(4)}$$
The base cases are trivial.

**First Step:** Prove (2).

Now, adding (3) and (4), we obtain :
\begin{align}
2F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2-F_{n-1}^2 &= F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}\\\\
(F_{n+1}-F_n)^2+F_{n+1}^2 + 2F_{n+1}F_n - F_{n-1}^2&= F_{2n+2}\\\\
(F_{n-1})^2+F_{n+1}^2 + 2F_{n+1}F_n - F_{n-1}^2&= F_{2n+2}\\\\
(F_{n+1}+F_{n})^2-F_{n}^2&= F_{2n+2}\\\\
F_{n+2}^2-F_{n}^2&= F_{2n+2} \quad \text{(2)}
\end{align}
As desired. $\square$

**Second Step**: Prove (1). Now that we have (2), we are home free!

Adding (2) and (3), we obtain :

\begin{align}
F_{n+2}^2-F_n^2+F_{n}^2+F_{n+1}^2 &= F_{2n+2}+F_{2n+1}\\\\
F_{n+2}^2+F_{n+1}^2 &= F_{2n+3} \quad \text{(1)}
\end{align}
And we are done. $\square$